# How can I prevent detached monitors from disappearing?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, disconnect

In a multi-monitor setup, when I physically disconnect a monitor it goes blank but Ubuntu won't mind, when I re-attach it, image comes back alright.

Now, I put HDMI switches into the signal path to switch between computers.

When I switch away from the Ubuntu machine, it will now "lose" the monitor and rearrange the "remaining" displays, re-distribute windows, taskbars etc.

Why does it do that when on HDMI switch and how can I prevent this?

Comment: You have to add the monitors EDID information to your xorg configuration.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858798/possible-to-have-xrandr-not-react-to-unplug-of-secondary-monitor-removal-of-hdm